# Two versions of arithmetic instructions in RISC. One modifies the flags and the other doesn't

Tags: computer-architecture

I've read that in RISC architecture most arithmetic instructions have two "*versions*":

- one that modifies the flags after calculations
- one that doesn't modify any flags.

My question is: **why is it so**?

Comment: this answers my question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/30485/32278.