# What is the reason or advantage of having special purpose status flags for the result of comparisons?

Tags: cpu, c, assembly, instruction-set

The C semantics treat the result of a comparison or any `true`/`false` operation as just an `int` with value `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`. This is simple and intuitive.

However, mainstream processors do not work this way. Comparison instructions do not output a byte or integer or any value with `1` or `0` as the result of the comparisons. Rather, they store the comparison results in a special purpose flags register. Then, to use the result of the comparison as an `int`, more instructions which [may or may not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27947306/16217248) even result in a branch, to actually extract the bit.

What is the reason for this? What is the advantage of using a special purpose flags register for comparisons or similar operations instead of simply return a ready-to-use integer result, the same way arithmetic operators do?

Comment: Think the question is a dup of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30477/why-do-cpu-architectures-use-a-flags-register-advantages

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. Either you have separate compare instructions for ==, !=, <, <= etc. which all create 0 or 1,  or you have one compare instruction creating flags and various branch instructions. Just s matter of choice.

However, it seems that storing the result of a compare instruction in a special place where it can be accessed directly by the branch unit, and especially can be accessed to resolve predicted branches, seems beneficial. And the result of a comparison in a general purpose register is usually *not* “ready to use” for its main purpose, which is making decisions.

Also consider that operations like add, multiply, subtract, shifts or sign extend may set these flags, so “if (x+y > 0)”, “if (x * y < 0)” etc. can be done by performing the operation and using a conditional branch.